# Windows 2008R2 RemoteAPP Failover

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, high-availability, remoteapp

I'm trying to setup 2 remoteapp servers with a bit of fail-over in the design.  I keep running into a few dead ends where there is no load balancing... or connections take a ridiculous amount of time to reconnect if the gateway fails... or broken sessions won't resume when reconnecting (starts new session instead)...

*Can someone explain how the whole process functions  a bit more clearly?*  Or give me a definitive answer on what works with what and what must be on a separate server from what... etc...

My understanding of the process is as follows...  *please correct me where I'm wrong*:

1. Client attempts to connect to FQDN provided using RDP.  Firewall is set to reject RDP traffic (port 3389 stuff).
2. Client uses public FQDN to make HTTPS connection to 1 of the two gateway services  (using 1 public IP NAT'd to private IP that's clustered to both servers using NLB).
3. Gateway service looks at the server farm members and bridges connection from HTTPS client to either remoteapp server in round-robin fashion (using private IP & rdp).
4. remoteapp server connects to session broker server which redirects the gateway service to the correct server (either reconnects existing session or creates a new session in a load-balanced manner).

Where I'm at now... The gateway servers are working like they should... but it seems that load-balancing isn't happening at all with the connection broker.  All connections (from gateway to RDP) end up on the same server... unless that server becomes unavailable (i.e. shutdown/yank network cable/etc...).  Anyone have any ideas?